# Compute permutations following specific constraints

Tags: r, data.table, permutation, circular-permutations

I want to store all feasible permutations for a target vector of size 24, that consists of (0,1).

For memory efficiency I use the below:

```
Test = data.table(permutations(n = 2,r = 12,v = c("zero","one"),repeats.allowed = T))
Test[, names(Test) := lapply(.SD, function(x) gsub("zero", "0,0", x))]
Test[, names(Test) := lapply(.SD, function(x) gsub("one", "1,1", x))]
```

Final output should adhere the following:

1. Minimum number of consecutive 1's is 8 and maximum is 15 in the middle of the vector.
2. At the start/end only consecutive 1's are permitted to be less than 8
3. two 0's between consecutive 1's

Examples:

`c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)` - Correct

`c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)` - Correct

`c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)` - Correct

`c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)` - Correct

`c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)` - Wrong: only 2 consecutive 1's

`c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1)` - Wrong: only one 0 between consecutive 1's at the end of the vector

Comment: Why is the fourth example correct?  It doesn't have "consecutive ones" at the start or at the end.  And the third example has consecutive zeroes at the end.  That appears incorrect as well...

Comment: I re-expressed the constraints. I hope now it makes sense

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your create permutations of `c("zero","one")` and then replace with 0, 0 and 1, 1. What's the point? Why not start with `c(0, 1)` ?

Comment: I do this because I want at least 2 zeros between 0-1 switches. Also the total number of permutations for a target vector of length 24 is 17M and I dont think this manageable.

Comment: 17M should be pretty manageable

Comment: If you use the `bit` package, you can store 0/1 as single bit instead of 32-bit integer. Then 17M * 24 elements is 48.6 Mb. Even if you use `integer` storage, it's about 1.5 Gb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand, for large number of consecutive ones in the middle, here is something to get started:

```
N <- 24

k <- 15L
npad <- 2L
m <- N - k - 2*npad
apply(expand.grid(0L:1L, 0L:1L, 1L:m), 1L, function(x) {
    y <- rep.int(c(x["Var1"], 0L, 1L, 0L, x["Var2"]), 
        c(x["Var3"], 2L, k, 2L, m - x["Var3"]))
    paste(y, collapse="")
})
```

output for `k=15`:

```
 [1] "000111111111111111000000" "100111111111111111000000" "000111111111111111001111" "100111111111111111001111"
 [5] "000011111111111111100000" "110011111111111111100000" "000011111111111111100111" "110011111111111111100111"
 [9] "000001111111111111110000" "111001111111111111110000" "000001111111111111110011" "111001111111111111110011"
[13] "000000111111111111111000" "111100111111111111111000" "000000111111111111111001" "111100111111111111111001"
[17] "000000011111111111111100" "111110011111111111111100" "000000011111111111111100" "111110011111111111111100"
```

Is `111111111111111000000000` and `011111111111111100000000` required as well? If yes, there is a need to loop the above for values of `0L` and `1L` instead of just `2L`

output for `k=8`:

```
 [1] "000111111110000000000000" "100111111110000000000000" "000111111110011111111111" "100111111110011111111111"
 [5] "000011111111000000000000" "110011111111000000000000" "000011111111001111111111" "110011111111001111111111"
 [9] "000001111111100000000000" "111001111111100000000000" "000001111111100111111111" "111001111111100111111111"
[13] "000000111111110000000000" "111100111111110000000000" "000000111111110011111111" "111100111111110011111111"
[17] "000000011111111000000000" "111110011111111000000000" "000000011111111001111111" "111110011111111001111111"
[21] "000000001111111100000000" "111111001111111100000000" "000000001111111100111111" "111111001111111100111111"
[25] "000000000111111110000000" "111111100111111110000000" "000000000111111110011111" "111111100111111110011111"
[29] "000000000011111111000000" "111111110011111111000000" "000000000011111111001111" "111111110011111111001111"
[33] "000000000001111111100000" "111111111001111111100000" "000000000001111111100111" "111111111001111111100111"
[37] "000000000000111111110000" "111111111100111111110000" "000000000000111111110011" "111111111100111111110011"
[41] "000000000000011111111000" "111111111110011111111000" "000000000000011111111001" "111111111110011111111001"
[45] "000000000000001111111100" "111111111111001111111100" "000000000000001111111100" "111111111111001111111100"
```

Comment: thanx for the help, I think it makes things simple! Cheers!